# Vue.js equivalent of data_get php

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, vuejs2

I am relatively new to vue.js and stumbled on this issue.

In php i can use `data_get($variable, 'field')` to get for example back the `$variable->field` value.

Now i am searching for a way to do this in vue js:

```js
<tr v-for="result in laravelData.data" :key="result.id">
  <td v-for="column in settings.fields.columns" :key="column.id" v-if="column.display">{{result.{{column.display}}}}</td>
</tr>
```

Of course this trows an error, but i am looking voor a way how i should do this `{{result.{{column.display}}}}`

Comment: So you want value from `results` on the position where is a `column` in `fields.columns`?

Answer (score 1):

Using lodash here seems like overkill since you just need a single object attribute and not need to check for nested attributes.

Just try this:

```
result[column.display_field]
```

It's just pure JavaScript. You can try it in your console by running this as well

```
result = { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' }
>> Object { a: "foo", b: "bar" }
field = 'a'
>> "a"
result[field]
>> "foo"
```

Comment: I was already using lodash in my project somewhere else so for me this is no overkill. I have tried youre method but can't get it to work, maybe it is some syntax thing in combination with vue. For now i stick by lodash, thank you!

Comment: This approach should definitely work, and it's always better to to use vanilla Javascript for simple things instead of a library.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself with lodash:

```js
_.get(result, column.display_field)
```